# How to conditionally mutate a new column when data is in long format, and condition is depending on grouping combination

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data in long format, and I'm trying to test each row against the mean of a certain grouping combination, in order to generate a new column with the conclusion from that test.

### Example

In this toy example, I have data about 20 cars. Each car could be of one of three possible makers. We have mpg data for each car, measured 8 times: in the city or highway, in the morning or evening, during the winter or spring.

```r
library(tidyr)

set.seed(2021)

df_id_and_makers <-
  data.frame(id = 1:20,
             maker = sample(c("toyota", "audi", "bmw"), size = 20, replace = TRUE))


df <- tidyr::expand_grid(df_id_and_makers,
                         road_type = c("city", "highway"),
                         time_of_day = c("morning", "evening"),
                         season = c("winter", "spring"))

df$mpg_val <- sample(15:40, size = nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

df
#> # A tibble: 160 x 6
#>       id maker road_type time_of_day season mpg_val
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>       <chr>    <int>
#>  1     1 bmw   city      morning     winter      28
#>  2     1 bmw   city      morning     spring      22
#>  3     1 bmw   city      evening     winter      40
#>  4     1 bmw   city      evening     spring      18
#>  5     1 bmw   highway   morning     winter      19
#>  6     1 bmw   highway   morning     spring      36
#>  7     1 bmw   highway   evening     winter      30
#>  8     1 bmw   highway   evening     spring      16
#>  9     2 audi  city      morning     winter      33
#> 10     2 audi  city      morning     spring      18
#> # ... with 150 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

I want to analyze this data to test my hypothesis that mpg in city is larger than mpg in highway. To this end, I want to create a new column that tests whether the value in `mpg_val` when `road_type` is `city` is larger than the *mean* of `mpg_val` across rows where `road_type` is `highway`. Furthermore, I want to compare just among cars of the same makers.

So, for example, `id = 1` is `bmw`, and therefore the new column I want to compute should test each value of `mpg_val` in rows where `road_type == city` (i.e., rows 1-4, but not 5-6), and see whether `mpg_val` is larger than `mean(mpg_val)` in rows where `road_type == highway` **and** `maker == bmw`.

### Expected output

Here's the manual and dumb way of doing this. I'll show only how I do this for `maker = bmw` for the sake of demonstration.

```r
library(dplyr)

# step 1 -- calculate the mean of `mpg_val` for `road_type = highway` and only across bmw
mean_bmw_highway_mpg <-
  df %>%
  filter(maker == "bmw",
         road_type == "highway") %>%
  pull(mpg_val) %>%
  mean()

mean_bmw_highway_mpg 
## [1] 26.22222


# step 2 -- compare each row where `maker = "bmw"` and `road_type = "city"` for its `mpg_val` against `mean_bmw_highway_mpg` 
result_bmw_only <-
  df %>%
  mutate(is_mpg_city_larger_than_mpg_highway = case_when(maker != "bmw" ~ "not_relevant",
                                                         road_type != "city" ~ "not_relevant",
                                                         mpg_val > mean_bmw_highway_mpg ~ "yes",
                                                         TRUE ~ "no"))

result_bmw_only 

## # A tibble: 160 x 7
##       id maker road_type time_of_day season mpg_val is_mpg_city_larger_than_mpg_highway
##    <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>       <chr>    <int> <chr>                              
##  1     1 bmw   city      morning     winter      28 yes  ## because 28 > 26.222                              
##  2     1 bmw   city      morning     spring      22 no   ## because 22 < 26.222                              
##  3     1 bmw   city      evening     winter      40 yes                                
##  4     1 bmw   city      evening     spring      18 no                                 
##  5     1 bmw   highway   morning     winter      19 not_relevant                       
##  6     1 bmw   highway   morning     spring      36 not_relevant                       
##  7     1 bmw   highway   evening     winter      30 not_relevant                       
##  8     1 bmw   highway   evening     spring      16 not_relevant                       
##  9     2 audi  city      morning     winter      33 not_relevant                       
## 10     2 audi  city      morning     spring      18 not_relevant                       
## # ... with 150 more rows
```

How could I achieve the same result as `result_bmw_only` (but applied to the entire `df`) in a more elegant way? Hopefully using `dplyr` approach, because this is what I'm used to, but otherwise any method will do.

Thanks!

---

EDIT 1

---

One solution I could think of involves `purrr`, but I can't get this done yet.

```r
library(purrr)

solution_purrr <-
  df %>%
  group_by(maker) %>%
  nest(data = -maker) %>%
  mutate(tbl_with_desired_new_col = map(.x = data, 
                    .f = ~ .x %>%
                      mutate(is_mpg_city_lrgr_thn_mpg_hwy = case_when(road_type != "city" ~ "not_relevant",
                                                                      mpg_val > mean(mpg_val) ~ "yes",
                                                                      TRUE ~ "no"))))
```

It seems that `solution_purrr` gets the desired output, but not exactly. This is because the second logic in `case_when` (i.e., `mpg_val > mean(mpg_val) ~ "yes"`) is not what I want. I want to compare `mpg_val` to `mean(mpg_val)` when that mean is computed based only on rows where `road_type == "highway"`. But here `mean(mpg_val)` computes across all rows.

---

EDIT 2

---

Based on @Till's answer below, I'd like to clarify that I'm looking for a solution that avoids a separate calculation of the mean we want to test against. What I did above with `mean_bmw_highway_mpg` is the undesired way of working towards the output. I showed `mean_bmw_highway_mpg` only for demonstrating the kind of mean I need to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got this. The following solution is based on both my *EDIT 1* above, as well as @MrFlick's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68297522/how-to-mutate-a-new-column-based-on-whether-col-a-is-larger-than-mean-of-col-b#comment120705809_68297522).

First, we define a helper function:

```r
is_x_larger_than_mean_y <- function(x, y) {
  x > mean(y)
}
```

Then, we run:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(maker) %>%
  nest(data = -maker) %>%
  mutate(tbl_with_desired_new_col = map(.x = data, 
                                        .f = ~ .x %>%
                                          mutate(is_mpg_city_lrgr_thn_mpg_hwy = case_when(road_type != "city" ~ "not_relevant",
                                                                                          is_x_larger_than_mean_y(mpg_val, mpg_val[road_type == "highway"]) ~ "yes",
                                                                                          TRUE ~ "no")))) %>%
  select(-data) %>%
  unnest(cols = tbl_with_desired_new_col)
```

This way, the line within `case_when()` that says `is_x_larger_than_mean_y(mpg_val, mpg_val[road_type == "highway"]) ~ "yes"` ensures that we compute the mean of `mpg_val` only based on rows in which `road_type == "highway"`.

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is already close. Take a look at the documentation of `dplyr::group_by()`
it is designed for these kinds of operations.

Below is how you can expand your BMW-only solution to the full dataset using `group_by()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mean_highway_mpg_df <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(road_type == "highway") %>% 
  group_by(maker) %>% 
  summarise(mean_highway_mpg = mean(mpg_val))
  
result_df <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(road_type == "city") %>% 
  group_by(maker) %>% 
  left_join(mean_highway_mpg_df) %>% 
  mutate(mpg_city_higher_highway = mpg_val > mean_highway_mpg)
#> Joining, by = "maker"

result_df %>% 
  select(-(time_of_day:season))
#> # A tibble: 80 x 6
#> # Groups:   maker [3]
#>       id maker road_type mpg_val mean_highway_mpg mpg_city_higher_highway
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>       <int>            <dbl> <lgl>                  
#>  1     1 bmw   city           28             26.2 TRUE                   
#>  2     1 bmw   city           22             26.2 FALSE                  
#>  3     1 bmw   city           40             26.2 TRUE                   
#>  4     1 bmw   city           18             26.2 FALSE                  
#>  5     2 audi  city           33             28.1 TRUE                   
#>  6     2 audi  city           18             28.1 FALSE                  
#>  7     2 audi  city           35             28.1 TRUE                   
#>  8     2 audi  city           36             28.1 TRUE                   
#>  9     3 audi  city           25             28.1 FALSE                  
#> 10     3 audi  city           32             28.1 TRUE                   
#> # … with 70 more rows
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not quite the solution I'm aiming for. I want to avoid a separate calculation such as `mean_highway_mpg_df `. I'll update the post to clarify that.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a "separate" calculation? Trying to cramp everything into a single block often leads to very convoluted code. My answer on the other hand is quite straight forward, is fast even with quite large datasets and answers your original question.