# How to mutate a new column based on whether col A is larger than mean of col B, under certain values of col C?

Tags: r, dplyr

This question diverts from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68292036/6105259). I want to mutate a new column based on the condition: *is a value in column `a` larger than the mean of column `b`*?

To this end, I can define the following function:

```r
is_x_larger_than_mean_y <- function(x, y) {
  x > mean(y)
}
```

And then use `dplyr::mutate()` such as:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(is_disp_larger_than_hp_mean = is_x_larger_than_mean_y(x = disp, y = hp))

##                     cyl  disp  hp is_disp_larger_than_hp_mean
## Mazda RX4             6 160.0 110                        TRUE
## Mazda RX4 Wag         6 160.0 110                        TRUE
## Datsun 710            4 108.0  93                       FALSE
## Hornet 4 Drive        6 258.0 110                        TRUE
## Hornet Sportabout     8 360.0 175                        TRUE
## Valiant               6 225.0 105                        TRUE
## Duster 360            8 360.0 245                        TRUE
## Merc 240D             4 146.7  62                        TRUE
## Merc 230              4 140.8  95                       FALSE
## Merc 280              6 167.6 123                        TRUE
## Merc 280C             6 167.6 123                        TRUE
## Merc 450SE            8 275.8 180                        TRUE
## Merc 450SL            8 275.8 180                        TRUE
## Merc 450SLC           8 275.8 180                        TRUE
## Cadillac Fleetwood    8 472.0 205                        TRUE
## Lincoln Continental   8 460.0 215                        TRUE
## Chrysler Imperial     8 440.0 230                        TRUE
## Fiat 128              4  78.7  66                       FALSE
## Honda Civic           4  75.7  52                       FALSE
## Toyota Corolla        4  71.1  65                       FALSE
## Toyota Corona         4 120.1  97                       FALSE
## Dodge Challenger      8 318.0 150                        TRUE
## AMC Javelin           8 304.0 150                        TRUE
## Camaro Z28            8 350.0 245                        TRUE
## Pontiac Firebird      8 400.0 175                        TRUE
## Fiat X1-9             4  79.0  66                       FALSE
## Porsche 914-2         4 120.3  91                       FALSE
## Lotus Europa          4  95.1 113                       FALSE
## Ford Pantera L        8 351.0 264                        TRUE
## Ferrari Dino          6 145.0 175                       FALSE
## Maserati Bora         8 301.0 335                        TRUE
## Volvo 142E            4 121.0 109                       FALSE
```

So far so good.

---

But what I want is to test whether `x > mean(y)` when `mean(y)` is computed only based on *certain* `y` values. In the scenario of a data.frame, like the one here, I want the inclusion/exclusion criteria for those `y` values that enter the `mean()` calculation to be dependent on that row value in a different column.

Back to the `mtcars` example, I want to test each value of `disp` against `mean(hp)` when `mean(hp)` includes only `hp` values for which `cyl == 8`.

```r
##                     cyl  disp  hp 
## Mazda RX4             6 160.0 110                        
## Mazda RX4 Wag         6 160.0 110                        
## Datsun 710            4 108.0  93                       
## Hornet 4 Drive        6 258.0 110      ## my mean of interest is the one based on values marked with `***`                        
## Hornet Sportabout     8 360.0 175***   ## (175+245+180+180+180+205+215+230+150+150+245+175+264+335)/14             
## Valiant               6 225.0 105      ## I want to compare EACH value of `disp` against that mean                        
## Duster 360            8 360.0 245***                     
## Merc 240D             4 146.7  62                        
## Merc 230              4 140.8  95                       
## Merc 280              6 167.6 123                        
## Merc 280C             6 167.6 123                        
## Merc 450SE            8 275.8 180***                     
## Merc 450SL            8 275.8 180***                     
## Merc 450SLC           8 275.8 180***                     
## Cadillac Fleetwood    8 472.0 205***                     
## Lincoln Continental   8 460.0 215***                     
## Chrysler Imperial     8 440.0 230***                     
## Fiat 128              4  78.7  66                       
## Honda Civic           4  75.7  52                       
## Toyota Corolla        4  71.1  65                       
## Toyota Corona         4 120.1  97                       
## Dodge Challenger      8 318.0 150***                     
## AMC Javelin           8 304.0 150***                     
## Camaro Z28            8 350.0 245***                     
## Pontiac Firebird      8 400.0 175***                     
## Fiat X1-9             4  79.0  66                       
## Porsche 914-2         4 120.3  91                       
## Lotus Europa          4  95.1 113                       
## Ford Pantera L        8 351.0 264***                     
## Ferrari Dino          6 145.0 175                       
## Maserati Bora         8 301.0 335***                     
## Volvo 142E            4 121.0 109
```

Is there a way to tweak my function `is_x_larger_than_mean_y()` to achieve this goal within the framework of `mutate()`? Otherwise, what would be a solution to this problem?

Comment: I think `mutate(is_disp_larger_than_hp_mean = is_x_larger_than_mean_y(x = disp, y = hp[cyl==8]))` is what you want? Is that right? Can you provide the desired output to verify?

Comment: @MrFlick, yes, this seems right! Would you mind posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard vector subsetting on your `y` values when passing them to your function

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(is_disp_larger_than_hp_mean = is_x_larger_than_mean_y(x = disp, y = hp[cyl==8]))
```

Here `hp[cyl==8]` will only return `hp` values where `cyl==8`

Answer (score 0):

An easy way only by using `group_by` is to create another column that takes the `mean` of `hp` values based on `cyl` categories and then assign the `y` in your function to this variable:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(hp_cyl = mean(hp)) %>%
  mutate(is_disp_larger_than_hp_cyl_mean = is_x_larger_than_mean_y(x = disp, y = hp_cyl))
```

You can further integrate this into your function if you want to keep things neat. However, I don't think it would be practical to do that without the use of `dplyr`.